# Пересылка бинарных данных: как правильно "принять\передать"?

Tags: сеть, c++

Есть клиент, [есть сервер, и между ними "посредник"](http://s018.radikal.ru/i528/1207/76/bf64fbf7294c.png). Клиент коннектится к посреднику, посредник тупо берет и перекидывает данные на сервер. Дело в том, что когда перекидывается текст (тестировал на http\ftp протоколах), то программа-"посредник" нормально передает данные. А вот когда бинарные... не уверен. Он их тоже передает, но программа клиент не может распознать так сказать данные.
Для передачи используется массив типа char. Возможно при приеме данных происходит переполнение некоторых элементов массива и данные искажаются? Мб стоит использовать другой тип данных для буфера?

Решил протестировать http, поднял сервер. Пытался скачать файл zip 2.9мб. Заметил, что когда выставляю размер буфера в "посреднике" на прием 3000 байт, скачивает 360кб и стопорится, когда 64б скачивает 2.6мб и стопорится; когда 8б, то браузер не совсем понимает, что ему приходит. Файл сплошным текстом открывает, да такое иногда бывает и в обычных интернетах. Также от размера входящего буфера в "посреднике" заметна разница в скорости. Как быть, не знаю. Да, в SDLNet, как было подмечено, есть функции для записи данных в межсетевой формат, чтобы обойти big endian \ little endian. Но я же сам у себя качал на локал хосте. Как бы такого не должно быть наверное в домашних условиях, на будущее да наверное стоит позаботиться.
Прикрепляю файлы проекта. Может у кого-то возникнет желание разобраться в коде. Для компиляции вам необходимо скачать и подинклудить [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/download-1.2.php) и [SDL_net](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_net) .

[Project file](http://zalivalka.ru/19424)

Тем кому лень скачивать, [вот листинги.](http://codepad.org/NXjTwqI6) 
main.cpp и tcputil.h

**Вопрос решен**

Спасибо участнику [**alexlz**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/352/alexlz) за подсказку. В итоге функции приема передачи выглядят так.

```
#ifndef tcputil_h
#define tcputil_h 1

#include "sdl/SDL.h"
#include "sdl/SDL_net.h"



const unsigned size=1024;
char* getMsg(TCPsocket sock,int &n)
{

    static char buf[size];
    n=SDLNet_TCP_Recv(sock,buf,size);
    /* get the string buffer over the socket */
    if(n<0)
    {
        if(SDLNet_GetError() && strlen(SDLNet_GetError())) /* sometimes blank! */
            printf("SDLNet_TCP_Recv: %s\n", SDLNet_GetError());
        //free(*buf);
        return NULL;
    }

    /* return the new buffer */
    return buf;
}

/* send a string buffer over a TCP socket with error checking */
/* returns 0 on any errors, length sent on success */
int putMsg(TCPsocket sock, char *str,int n)
{

    /* send the buffer, with the NULL as well */

    if(SDLNet_TCP_Send(sock,str,n)<n) {
        if(SDLNet_GetError() && strlen(SDLNet_GetError())) /* sometimes blank! */
            printf("SDLNet_TCP_Send: %s\n", SDLNet_GetError());
        return(0);
    }

    /* return the length sent */
    return n;
}
#endif
```

Ну и да стоило убрать всякие printf() как скорость передачи увеличилась до "глазом моргнуть не успеешь".

Comment: Огромное тебе СПАСИБО за подсказку. Пораскинув мозгами да ошибкой было использовать std::string изначально ф-ции принимали char * но я переделал на std::string для удобства когда делал "чат" потом перепастил.. код в общем не суть. Суть в том что это двоичные данные среди которых встречается \0 когда ... вывел размер полученного пакета и размер который показывает strlen() , оказалось что пришло допустим 1024 а strlen() говорит 453, и в итоге отсылает 453 байта , и иза потери данных файл приходил не весь , когда выставлял маленький буффер ~24б то файла "доходило" больше т.к потерь меньше.

Comment: Большое человеческое спасибо.

Comment: Большое пожалуйста, но я не имел в виду отказ от string, а только использование конструктора string с двумя параметрами char * и длина (не помню какого типа -- что-то производное от int). Т.е. типа

      str=string(buf, n);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++? std::string? Получите и распишитесь в получении. Преобразуете null-terminated char array (buf) в строку str и удивляетесь, почему пропадают данные после нуля? (Подсказка: длина принятого куска возвращается SDLNet_TCP_Recv)

Answer (score 0):

Логичнее было бы использовать массив типа **BYTE** (windows.h) имхо, это есть **UNSIGNED CHAR**. Так было бы благоразумнее. Вы пишете:

> Возможно, при приеме данных происходит переполнение некоторых элементов массива и данные искажаются.

Нет, это бы вызвало аварийное завершение в том программном компоненте, где происходил бы этот самый `OverFlow`. Что вызвало бы крах как минимум этого компонента, если не всей системы (клиент->посредник->сервер). Я вам советую поотлаживать вашу систему. Ведь мы не видим, что вы отсылаете. Поэтому, выведите, например, на сервере принятые бинарные данные.

Comment: Дело в том что я не знаю что конкретно отсылает клиент\сервер друг другу. 
Когда коннект идет на прямую клиент<->сервер то все нормально ... а когда клиент<->посредник<->сервер то нет .  Эксперементы показали что http\ftp данные нормально проходят. А от той программы нет. 
Насчет unsigned char попробую..

Comment: @SingleAsen, чем `BYTE[]` благоразумнее `unsigned char[]`?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, посредник меняет [порядок байт](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2), что-то типа big endian и little endian, так что почитайте по этой теме немного, может поможет.

Comment: Явно не оно. Тогда бы текст не проходил, а он проходит.

Подозреваю, что все более приземленно и посредник non-7bit-safe.

Comment: Ну я когда то писал сетевую прогу, так вот у меня текст норм шел, а бинарные данные были перевернуты.

Comment: @Roman Goriachevskiy, IMHO у Вас клиент и сервер работали на машинах с разным порядком байт.

Вообще, передавать двоичные данные лучше преобразуя их в сетевой порядок байт при отправке (htonl(),htons()) и обратно в порядок байт хоста при полученнии (ntohl(),ntohs()).

Но, похоже здесь не тот случай. С чего бы это прокси стал переупорядочивать байты в потоке ? Откуда ему внутренняя структура данных известна ?

На самом деле, хорошо бы про прокси побольще узнать.